# Mobo supports 16GB; only 4x4GB or also 2x8GB?

Tags: memory, memory-limit

My motherboard (gigabyte ga-ma790xt-ud4p) supports 16GB of DDR3 RAM.

Does this mean that it supports only 4x4GB or also other distributions, like 2x8GB or 1x16GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, if you can get 1x16, it will be VERY expensive... 2x8GB will also be pricey.

Quite frankly, your board supports dual channel and a maximum of 16GB, I can not see any limitations or maximum memory module listed but, you would be silly going for anything other than 4x4GB on the grounds of price and the fact that the board supports dual channel mode.

Comment: Usually there is a max on the size of the DIMM also.

Comment: Populating all four banks will stress the mobo, if he's thinking about overclocking he'll lose a lot in comparison to the amount of voltage he'll need. Also all four banks populated will need the RAM given voltage above spec.

Comment: @Surfasb mentions a very good point, usually home motherboards support a maximum of 8GB sticks - but, these are usually very expensive and personally I have never seen 16GB sticks. I did not mention this however as I couldn't find a maximum listed in the specifications of manual.

Comment: @SandeepBansal: Populating all four banks **does not require overvoltage**.  Only when you need to improve your timings. . .

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, this site [Gigabyte ga-ma790x-ud4p](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3038#sp) states, the memory is DDR2 and not DDR3 - In my opinion, I would opt for 4x4GB DDR2 since you will get better performance from the Dual channel architecture.

Comment: Missed the `T` in the name, sorry. The `T`-version does have DDR3